# Scalar-by-matrix derivative involving trace and Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, hadamard-product

I am quite new to matrix calculus, and I am trying to find the scalar-by-matrix derivative to a seemingly simple problem but have yet to find a solution online. I am trying to find
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\text{Tr}\left((\mathbf{X}\circledast\mathbf{A})^T\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{X}\circledast\mathbf{A})\right),
\end{align}
where $\circledast$ denotes the Hadamard product. 
Does anyone know how to compute the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new variable.$$\eqalign{
Y &= A\circledast X \quad\implies\; dY = A\circledast dX \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm Tr}(Y^TBY) \\&= B:YY^T \\
d\phi
 &= B:(Y\,dY^T+dY\,Y^T) \\
 &= (B+B^T):dY\,Y^T \\
 &= (BY+B^TY):dY \\
 &= (BY+B^TY):A\circledast dX \\
 &= A\circledast (BY+B^TY):dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
 &= A\circledast (BY+B^TY) \\
\\}$$
**NB:** In the above, a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$\;P:Q = {\rm Tr}(P^TQ)$.

The properties of the trace allow terms in a trace product to be rearranged in any number of ways.
$$\eqalign{
P:Q &= P^T:Q^T &= Q:P \\
P:QR &= PR^T:Q &= Q^TP:R \\
}$$
The Hadamard product is commutative, allowing its terms to be rearranged as well.
$$\eqalign{
P\circledast Q &= Q\circledast P \\
}$$
Finally, the Hadamard and trace products commute with one another.
$$\eqalign{
P:Q\circledast R &= P\circledast Q:R \\
}$$

Comment: I tried to replicate the procedure for \Tr((X\circledast A)B(X\circledast A)^T) (i.e., switching the transposes) to make sure I understood it correctly, and I got A\circledast(YB+YB^T). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.